# Stuck in Grub Rescue

Tags: linux, windows-7, boot, grub, ubcd

I had a dual boot laptop which I had to fix, so I figured I just had to delete the Linux partitions and reinstall Windows.

After formatting the Linux partitions and rebooting to reinstall Windows I got the "Grub Rescue" screen.

I tried following the directions given on grub rescue (ls, set prefix, set root, insmode normal) but this didn't work.

Is it possible to fix this using Ultimate Boot CD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Insert your cd and boot from that cd. To boot from that cd, restart and keep typing f9 as soon as the windows logo appears. This key might be different, based on your laptop model.
Now enter language and then select troubleshoot, then select command prompt and enter the command `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. Now you can exit the command prompt by command `exit`. Then simply restart you laptop and everything will be normal